# One of the value is returning null in model which is assigned in the entity class as an object

Tags: entity-framework, model-view-controller

I am trying to return values to my view from a view model which has entity class objects.
Category class has List Products in it, but when i am displaying the values on the view from the model it returns null value in the category.model.count
[image]
View Code:

```
`@model ClothBazar.Web.ViewModels.CategorySearchViewModel
<div>
    <table class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Category Name</th>
                <th>Product Count</th>
                <th>Actions</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
         @if (Model.Categories != null && Model.Categories.Count > 0)
         {
            foreach (var category in Model.Categories)
            {


                <tr>
                    <td>@category.Name</td>
                    <td>
                        @category.Products.Count
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <button class="editBtn" data-id="@category.ID">Edit</button>
                        <button class="deleteBtn" data-id="@category.ID">Delete</button>
                    </td>
                </tr>

            }
         }

        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>`
```

CategorySearchviewmodel code

```
public class CategorySearchViewModel
    {
        public string SearchTerm { get; set; }
        public List<Category> Categories { get; set; }
    }
```

Category class:

```
public class Category : BaseEntities
{
    public string ImageURL { get; set; }
    public List<Product> Products { get; set; }
    public bool IsFeatured { get; set; }
}
```

Controller action code :

```
 public ActionResult CategoryTable(string Search)
    {
        CategorySearchViewModel model = new CategorySearchViewModel();
        model.Categories = categoryService.GetCategories();
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Search) == false)
        {
            model.SearchTerm = Search;
            model.Categories = model.Categories.Where(x=> x.Name != null && x.Name.ToLower().Contains(Search.ToLower())).ToList();
        }
        return PartialView("CategoryTable", model);
    }
```

GetCategories Method:

```
 public List<Category> GetCategories()
    {
        using(var context = new CBContext())
        {
           return context.Categories.ToList();
        }
    }
```

Comment: You need to show the query that loads the data, this looks like it could be a lazy loading vs eager loading issue. Your image clearly shows that in memory `Category.Products` is null for the _women's category_

Comment: i added that now

Comment: Thanks alot Chris the issue was of lazy loading vs eager loading i applied eager loading now and its working perfectly fine Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

The issue was of type of loading before i was using lazy loading.
After using eager loading it works fine

```
public List<Category> GetCategories()
    {
        using(var context = new CBContext())
        {
            return context.Categories.Include(x => x.Products).ToList();
        }
    }
```